# Xerox WorkCentre 6515 is not printing from Windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, printer

My iPad and Windows 10 laptop are connected with the same wifi.

Using iPad, I can print and scan from WorkCentre 6515. I am unable to print from Windows 10 laptop.

I downloaded driver (Xerox Smart Start – Driver Installer) from the link https://www.support.xerox.com/en-us/product/workcentre-6515/downloads?platform=win10x64&language=en and installed.

I am able to scan successfully.

I accessed router and found printer IP. The printer IP is 10.0.0.14.
[image]

Printer is accessible and I can ping printer IP also.

However, at the router page, I see printer is under *Offline Devices*.

Now I downloaded PCL6 Print Driver for Administrators and PostScript Driver - Xerox User Interface - Microsoft Certified from the link https://www.support.xerox.com/en-us/product/workcentre-6515/downloads?platform=win10x64&language=en and installed.

Print command goes to the printer but no printing done.

I run troubleshoot but no use.

Please let me know, how to resolve it?

With Regards
FewL

Comment: See (ask Xerox) if it still needs SMBv1 to connect.

Comment: What about (ask Xerox)? I already posted this question at https://forum.support.xerox.com. No one replied. As product is out of warranty so Xerox is not interested for technical troubleshoot. What is SMBv1?

Comment: SMBv1 is a connection protocol - gone in Windows 10 replaced by SMBv2 for security reasons.

Comment: Okay. Now what I need to do?

Comment: You may need to replace the printer. Downgrading to SMBv1 is a very risky thing to do.  I do not recommend that.

Comment: Here is a Microsoft Article on SMB that may help you.  ....  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3

Comment: How do I know, SMBv2 or SMBv3 can be cause of this issue?

Comment: The older Xerox printer likely uses SMBv1.  If a printer supports SMBv2 it should print.

Comment: Great point. I gone through the printer manual but I didn't find. How do I know, the printer supports SMBv1 or SMBv2?

Comment: I am not sure. It has been a while since clients had older printers. If there is no mention, it may only support SMBv1 (very common for older printers).

Comment: SMB (ports 139 & 445) is not needed for printing, which uses ports 515 or 9100. You say "Print command goes to the printer". Does that mean the printer's display indicates it is receiving? If yes, then it is possible the printer is trying to interpret the PCL data as PostScript, and nothing will be printed. If this is the case, you can change the printer's setting (or the driver).

Comment: I found technical specifications of the printer at https://www.office.xerox.com/latest/65XSS-02U.PDF. Pls look and let me know.

Comment: At Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Devices and Printers printer added twice. I checked printing from both one-by-one. One says, printing but no print came out from the printer. Another says, Job Failed message at computer. In case of troubleshooting, it tries to connect with printer.

Comment: I am unable to understand, if connectivity issue is there, why printer IP is able to ping successfully from the computer. At web-browser, I am able to access printer information. Pls look image in the question. Also I am able to scan from the computer. At another side, printer is showing under Offline Devices at router login page.

Comment: You did not answer my question: does the printer's display indicate it is receiving data when you try to print? If it is, try using the PostScript driver, from https://www.support.xerox.com/en-ps/product/workcentre-6515/downloads?platform=win10x64&language=en

Comment: Printer's display is not indicating , it is receiving data. However, I installed PostScript driver. After installing PostScript driver, new printer added at Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Devices. When I give print command from new added printer, it's failed.

Comment: I did Default Factory Reset. While setup, I selected Ethernet. Default selected apps are Email, Fax and Scan to. If leave all checked, SMTP server is required for Email, Fax number is required for Fax and Network is required for Scan to.

Comment: In the Network, available options are Network (SMB), FTP, SFTP. I selected SMB. The error message,  "An error has occurred. If the error persists, power off, then power on. (in a box is X Close)

Comment: Moreover, I have seen, in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features, in Turn Windows features on or off and in Windows features, SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support tree is checked.

Comment: Previously the printer was able to scan & print from iPad. After Default Factory Reset, it’s not working from iPad also. Pls let me know, what I need to do further?

Answer (score 0):

> Print command goes to the printer but no printing done.

Does the job ever appear in the Jobs app on the machine?

If the job never reached the printer, make sure port 9100 is enabled, as this is what Xerox Smart Start uses. To check if this is the case, log into the Embedded Web Server as the administrator and click **Connections**, or print a configuration report from the printer's control panel.

If this still doesn't work, make sure there aren't any firewalls or network devices blocking TCP port 9100. SMB shouldn't have anything to do with this.

---

You said you got this message after a factory reset:

> An error has occurred. If the error persists, power off, then power on.

Is there a fault code on the screen?